Fiori Elements Object Page Custom Action Button Type
My goal is to have two buttons in the footer of a Fiori Elements object page.
One button is to accept the entity, and the other is to reject the entity on the object page.
To emphasize this, I want to use the button types "Accept" and "Reject."
Here is the code in my manifest (generated with the VS Code Fiori extension for guided development):
"sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
    "sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage.view.Details": {
        "controllerName": "appid.ext.controller.ObjectPageExt",
        "sap.ui.generic.app": {
            "type1": {
                 "EntitySet": "set1",
                  "Header": {
                      "Actions": {
                          "disbursementLoan": {
                              "id": "action1",
                              "text": "{@i18n>}",
                              "press": "action1",
                              "requiresSelection": false,
                              "determining": true
                          },
                          "refejectDokuments": {
                              "id": "action2",
                              "text": "{@i18n>}",
                              "press": "action2",
                              "requiresSelection": false,
                              "determining": true
                          }                                       
                      }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
     }

I tried to add the sap.m.button property type, like "type": "Accept", but the buttons do not appear with their respective types.
Is there a different way to add custom actions/buttons to the footer bar or header of the object page, where I can control the button type?
Thanks in advance,
Eric

For RAP actions you can use the property criticality, see the official documentation for more info.
For custom actions you have to use JS code. In your controller extension get the button and set the button type.
sap.ui.define(
    ["sap/m/library"],
    (mLibrary) => {

        const { ButtonType } = mLibrary;

        return {
            onAfterRendering() {
                this._getAction1Button().setType(ButtonType.Accept);
            },

            _getAction1Button() {
                return this.byId(this.getView().createId("action::action1"));
            }
        };
    },
);

Same for action2.

sadly i cannot use RAP because i am still on R3, i am trying the createID approach
